# How to make a Notification with different phone?

Tags: android

i want to make an application about how to receive Notification from other phone but i don't know how to do it,i'm already search the keyword still didn't have a match with my problem, please can u give me an advice or tell me how i'm gonna do it?thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use client-server communication for your requirement.
In that you have to follow step as:

1. Create server to listen client.
2. Retrieve notification from device A (as a client).
3. send data to device B(as a server).

you can refer link for server-client communication

- https://www.journaldev.com/741/java-socket-programming-server-client
- http://www.coderzheaven.com/2017/05/01/client-server-programming-in-android-send-message-to-the-client-and-back/